# Why is Logcat called LogCAT

Tags: android, logging, logcat, cat

I know how to use Logcat and what it is usefull for but I am wondering why Logcat is called Logcat. The log- part is obvious but the -cat part is not.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Asking "why did Developer X make Decision Y" on Stack Overflow is not especially useful. The only party who can answer definitively is Developer X, and odds are Developer X will not see or answer your question. Everybody else can just offer opinions.

Comment: I agree with you on that for the most cases but for tools like logcat the name and knowing why its named like that, it's hardly a random name, might provide an additional insight in understanding the tool. For smaller tools in general I totally agree with you but for general used tools like Logcat this seems to be the best platform of experts to ask this question to

Comment: "might provide an additional insight in understanding the tool" -- sure. That does not mean that Developer X will see or answer your question, and soliciting opinions is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 16):

Probably after Unix utility called `cat` - see the manual here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html

The name `cat` is a short for *concatenate*, as the tool can be used to join multiple files.

The `cat` tool is used frequently to e.g. show a file content on standard output (console). It's even common to call this operation *to cat the file*. I guess that's why we have `logcat` - it *cats* the log to standard output.

Comment: Can anyone provide a reference ?

Comment: @Ahsan no, there is none